# Putting a Category of posts under a Page

Tags: categories, pages, blog

I have a website, say `mysite.com`, and there is a blog `mysite.com/blog`. When I post a new post under the `blog` category its appears like `mysite.com/newpost`. I want the posts under the `blog` category to be displayed under the `blog` tag like `mysite.com/blog/newpost`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your permalinks to `/%category%/%postname%/`. This will set the category name in front of the post URL.

If you want to use the **fixed** string `blog`, set the permalinks to `/blog/%postname%/`.

Comment: Thanks,but what can i do if i do not want a post to appear within a category and will this change effect the page permalinks?

Comment: The second option is not related to categories, and yes, of course it will affect permalinks – that was your question after all.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what i was asking let me explain if there is a page called mysite.com/abc. abc is a page not a post.if i make the change as you have suggested will this effect this link.

Comment: No, this will change only post URLs, not pages.